# Inputstream not being read

Tags: java, io, openshift

I am new to JavaEE, but yeah. Everything is working just fine on my computer while I'm running the code, however when I send it to my server, my input isn't being read.... So I'm guessing there's something wrong with openshift or something that's causing it to not be read?

Edit: K, something really weird is going on now and it's not working on my computer now  either. I still have the same code though....

How I'm reading the data:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buff = new byte[5000];
    int amtRead;
    while ((amtRead = inputStream.read(buff)) != -1)
        bos.write(buff, 0, amtRead);
    inputStream.read(buff);
    data = bos.toByteArray();
```

How I'm sending the data:

```
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
    os.write(new byte[]{32, 33, 35, 36});
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    System.out.println(getText(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
```

And the output saying nothing has been written:

```
{"out":{"info":"Data wrote: []"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out why it was doing that.

So in my code is like this:

```
@Override
protected final void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    addQuery(req, resp);
    onPost(req, resp);
}
```

And since I was calling some methods on `req` (like `req.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")`, it seemed to be reading all of the input the inputstream had to offer before my real reader could read what was inside the input.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget you can only write to $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR (which is ~/app-root/data) or /tmp. Where are you writing your file to?